# Error while compiling java files and java-servlet files

Tags: java, servlets, classpath, tomcat9

I am currently new to java and servlets. I am using Apache Tomcat 9.0 as my server and creating the servlets.
The error I am getting or the place where I am getting stuck is that when I set CLASSPATH in the system variables as the location of "servlet-api.jar" file the servlet programs compile and run or function properly but not the simple java programs. And the reverse is also true, that is when I remove the CLASSPATH from system variables the servlet programs throw error and the normal java programs compile and run fine.
What to do please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your Servlet and other third party jar files in classpath while compiling with "**javac**" command using the "**-cp**" option.
Below command demonstrate adding two jar files in classpath servlet-api.jar and another.jar while compiling MyFirstServlet.java controller.

```
javac -cp "/path/to/your/servlet-api.jar:/path/to/your/another.jar;" MyFirstServlet.java
```

With this approach **you do not need to set CLASSPATH in the system variables** for your third party jar files.